# scope in javascript object

Tags: javascript, function, object, scope

Here's my code:

```
var Test = (function () {
    function Test() {
        this.sum = n;

        this.calculate();
    }

    Test.prototype.calculate = function() {
        n = 5;
        return n;
    }
    return Test;
})();

var mytest = new Test();
```

Could you please explain why n is undefined? I thought return n shoud help but I was wrong.

Comment: `n` *is* 5 after calling `calculate`, only you are getting an exception before. Have a look at your error console.

Comment: What are you trying to do? When do you expect `n` to be 5, what should return `n`? How did you test it?

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor function seems to have a bug. You are reading from `n` before assigning it.

Perhaps this would be clearer:

```
function Test() { this.sum = this.calculate(); }
```

Then get rid of the `n` value altogether.

```
Test.prototype.calculate = function() { return 5; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but try this:

```
var Test = (function () {
    function Test() {
        this.sum = this.calculate();
    }

    Test.prototype.calculate = function() {
        var n = 5;
        return n;
    }
    return Test;
})();

var mytest = new Test();
alert(mytest.sum); // 5
```

To answer your question - `n` was `undefined` because it had no value when you were trying to do `this.sum = n;`. It could have worked if you first invoked `this.calculate()` and then tried to assign `this.sum = n;`. But even in this case this was very wrong, since you were leaking variable `n` to the global namespace (when you do not explicitly initialize variable with `var`, it leaks to global namespace - `window`). So to illustrate what I mean - this could work:

```
var Test = (function () {
    function Test() {
        this.calculate();

        this.sum = n; // n is global now, hence accessible anywhere and is defined by this moment
    }

    Test.prototype.calculate = function() {
        n = 5; // not initialized with var so it leaks to global scope - gets accessible through window.n
        return n; // has no sense, since you do not use returned value anywhere
    }
    return Test;
})();

var mytest = new Test();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I try to explain a bit.

```
function Test() {
    this.sum = n; // assign undefined to this.sum

    this.calculate(); // n = 5, but doesn't affect this.sum as undefined is already passed to sum
}
```

correct behavior( what you wanted)

```
function Test() {

    this.calculate(); 
    this.sum = n; 

}
```